# Show posts in custom order

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, order

I am creating a custom plugin which shows custom order for posts for different categories. Hereby on plugin activation i am calling a function which stores order of newly created posts as

[image: Post Order]

here meta key is as follows the integer value is the category id

Given Below is the code that how i am creating these post meta entries.

```
function set_post_meta_entry() {
$categories = get_categories();
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $category_posts = get_posts(array(
        'category' => $category->term_id,
        'numberposts' => 30,
    ));

    $index = 1;
    foreach ($category_posts as $post) {
        update_post_meta($post->ID, 'test_' . $category->term_id.'_index', $index);
        $index++;
    }
}
```

}

The thing i want is that on the category page with id 36059 should show post in this order and after this order, rest of the post should display on the basis of published date.